# How to use ngrok to expose neo4j instance running on localhost to be used by google colab?

Tags: neo4j, google-colaboratory, py2neo, ngrok, neo4j-bolt

I am trying to use my local neo4j server through google colab.

I am using ngrok to expose the port using command:
`ngrok http 7687`. It gives something like this:
[image: ngrok]

ngrok is working fine.
But When trying to connect using colab, I am getting the following error:

[image: colab_py2neo]

Somehow, `port 7687` is being used by default but I don't need any port for this particular case.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bolt` port on 7687 is not on http, but on TCP.

You can use `ngrok tcp 7687` instead, you will need to open an account on ngrok in order to use the tcp forwarding feature.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the neo4j connection config, you need to replace tcp:// syntax with bolt:// at the first URL, so neo4j will recognize the connection. It's like this:

```
bolt://tcp.ngrok.io:3000
```